# How to ensure execvp() works?

Tags: c, linux

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
pid_t pid;
FILE * fp;
int main()
{
    char input[256];
    int i=0;
    while(fgets(input,256,stdin)!=NULL)
    {   
        char *string[strlen(input)];
        char *token=strtok(input," ");
        while(token!=NULL)
        {
            string[i++]=token;
            token=strtok(NULL," ");
        }
        string[i]=NULL;
        execvp(*string,string);   
        i=0;
    }

}
```

First, I will take `input` into `strtok9)`, and store them into `string`.
But `execvp()` always returns -1.
For example, `whoami` is one command I have tried, but it is not working.

Comment: Try printing the contents of `string` before the call to `execvp`, and using `perror` after to see why it failed.

Comment: You've not zapped the newline that `fgets()` stores in `input`; there isn't a program called `"whoami\n'`.  Use `" \n"` (or even `" \n\r"`) as the delimiter for `strtok()`.

Comment: If you define `int i = 0;` inside the loop (e.g. before you define `string`), you don't have to reset it at the end of the loop.  Or you could use `for (int i = 0; fgets(input, sizeof(input), stdin) != NULL; i = 0)` instead of a `while` loop.

Answer (score 0):

The fundamental problem is that you do not zap the newline stored by `fgets()`, so the command you try to execute is effectively `"whoami\n"`, which doesn't exist.  You can zap the newline by using `" \n"` as the delimiter string to `strtok()` — or you could use `" \n\r"` to handle DOS files on Unix systems.

You also need to use `fork()` if the loop is to be at all meaningful, and you need to wait in the parent for the child to complete.  You can use `wait()` or `waitpid()` for the task; `waitpid()` has some advantages over `wait()`, but the code below uses `wait()`.  Note that error messages should be printed to `stderr`, not `stdout`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static const char delim[] = " \n\r";

int main(void)
{
    char input[256];
    while (fgets(input, sizeof(input), stdin) != NULL)
    {
        int i = 0;
        char *string[strlen(input)];
        char *token = strtok(input, delim);
        while (token != NULL)
        {
            string[i++] = token;
            token = strtok(NULL, delim);
        }
        string[i] = NULL;
        pid_t pid = fork();
        if (pid < 0)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed to fork child process\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        else if (pid == 0)
        {
            execvp(*string, string);
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed to execute command [%s]\n", string[0]);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        else
        {
            int corpse;
            int status;
            while ((corpse = wait(&status)) > 0)
            {
                printf("%d: child %d exited with status 0x%.4X\n",
                       (int)getpid(), corpse, status);
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Example run:

```
$ ./ex89
whoami
jonathanleffler
22503: child 22505 exited with status 0x0000
who am i
jonathanleffler ttys001  Apr 27 00:08 
22503: child 22506 exited with status 0x0000
ls -ld ex89 ex89.c
-rwxr-xr-x  1 jonathanleffler  staff  9240 Apr 28 23:17 ex89
-rw-r--r--  1 jonathanleffler  staff  1119 Apr 28 23:17 ex89.c
22503: child 22507 exited with status 0x0000
$
```

There are many more files in the directory than just `ex89` and `ex89.c` — this shows that the arguments are being parsed (split) correctly.